# SCIM: What is the preferred no. of members should I return in Get group response or is it optional?

Tags: azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim, scim2

Can we limit the group members in SCIM Get Group response?
If we return all members in group response with heavy data then it will impact the performance.

**SCIM Get Group Response:**

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group"
    ],
    "id": "600",
    "externalId": "4a38d3xx-cdxx-45xx-a9xx-04d4ea26xxxx",
    "meta": {
        "resourceType": "Group",
        "created": "2021-03-11T10:20:44.267",
        "location": "https://api/V1/groups/600"
    },
    "displayName": "Test SCIMv3",
    "members":[{ 
        "value":"2", 
        "$ref":"https://api/V1/users/2" 
       }, 
       { 
        "value":"3", 
        "$ref":"https://api/V1/users/3" 
       },
       {...}
    ] 
}
```

If there is no limit in member list then can we remove the **members** attribute from the Group response itself?

Answer (score 1):

following some experience with Azure, as appears here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups
You have to support:
The filter excludedAttributes=members when querying the group resource  section 3.4.2.5
Azure sends get group by ID with this param usually, and you don't have to return members in this case.